# AccessibilityService static instance sometimes is null and I can't understand why or how to fix it

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

This is my AccesibilityService class:

```
public class MyAS extends AccessibilityService {

    public static MyAS myAS;


    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
        myAS = this;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
       
    }


    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        disableSelf();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }



    public static MyAS getMyAS(){
        return myAS;
    }


}
```

And this is my Service class:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        
        MyAS.getMyAS().dispatchGesture(...);
        
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


}
```

As you can see I basically assign the AccesibilityService instance to a static instance.
And then I use that static instance in MyService in order to dispatch a gesture.

On android 9 works fine, at least so far.
On android 11 sometimes works fine but other times sadly I get a `NullPointerException` because basically `MyAS.getMyAS()` return null. But the AccessibilityService is enabled, as a matter of fact I don't let the user start MyService unless the toggle of the AccessibilityService is on.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sometimes A11y services won't start if they've crashed a few times. If you could run your app where you know the AS is reference is null but it shouldn't be (you think the service is running) - you can run `adb shell settings get secure enabled_accessibility_services` to see if your AS is actually running (the package name should appear in there)

Comment: I don't understand the Accessibility Service well but I think the Android system will start it for you as long as it is enabled by the user in settings , and that creates another instance in the system. So the `onServiceConnected` method will store the local AS. instance but not the android system one , and when you call the `MyAS` it is referencing to the local class instead of the system one. ( ? )